# What does GB, MB, kB etc. mean in Microsoft Documentation?

Tags: units-of-measurement, microsoft-documentation

Does anyone know if in official technical Microsoft documentation (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits) there is a consistent interpretation of data size units? That is, do GB, MB, kB really mean Gigabyte, Megabyte, Kilobyte, or is it actually Gibybyte, Mebibyte, Kibibyte, or is it simply inconsistent and we have to guess what is actually meant?

For example, in the link above, they use `20 GB` which could well mean `2 * 10^9 B` (i.e. 20 GB). But on the same page, they also use `512 kB` which suggests a more natural interpretation of `2^19 B` (i.e. 512 KiB).

Comment: Actually they have `512 KB` (capital K), which is not really a thing. Assume the same level of consistency and attention to detail for the rest of the text.